API not working on react-native without SSL
I have been looking for the solution of a similar question but I couldn't find any. So that's why I am asking it here.
So I have deployed my api's on an AWS instance and whenever I try to access the api's from the browser they work properly. i.e if I do http://25.234.23.53:3030 I get the success message, but for some reason I am not able to use the AWS instance IP and port to call the API's from my react native Ios simulator.
Whenever I am calling the API from my react-native app, I'm getting this:

and referring to another similar question asked on stack overflow, I have also tried using this approach in my app's info.plist:
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>localhost</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>

"react-native version": "0.68.2",
Please guide me how can I allow my app to use http calls from my AWS instance?

You are on the right track with the ATS config, but you don't want to allow insecure access to local host. You are going to need to enable insecure access generally.  I hope this is a temporary situation and you plan to put your api behind TLS eventually?

How can I enable insecure access generally?
and yes this is just for internal testing I have an SSL based environment which will be used later @Paulw11

For testing, you can disable ATS entirely using
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
</dict>


Apparently, I had the fix within my code as mentioned by @Paulw11 within the reply as well.
I just trimmed the following code:
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>localhost</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>

into this:
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
</dict>

